# Postgres / slow query / order by

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, order-by, query-performance

I'm joining two tables, filter out results by second table and order results by first table's ID.

The query is super-slow on Postgres Database. I see the issue is in the ORDER BY statement. But increasing work_mem (SET LOCAL work_mem = '256MB';) didn't help.

```
select A.a_id
from B
inner join A 
on A.b_id=B.b_id
where
    A.date_one between '2012-01-07 04:05:06' and '2019-01-08 03:07:06'
 or A.date_two between '2012-01-07 04:05:06' and '2019-01-08 03:05:06'
order by A.a_id ASC 
limit 100;
```

Execution plan:

```
"Limit  (cost=690932.94..690933.19 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=19412.278..19412.344 rows=100 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=12521 read=287185"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=690932.94..698624.09 rows=3076458 width=8) (actual time=19412.274..19412.293 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: A.a_id"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=12521 read=287185"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=34731.92..573352.93 rows=3076458 width=8) (actual time=822.673..19052.607 rows=417486 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (A.b_id = BB.b_id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=12521 read=287185"
"              ->  Seq Scan on A  (cost=0.00..432736.38 rows=7512005 width=16) (actual time=0.044..9306.081 rows=7512001 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: (((date_one >= '2012-01-07 04:05:06-05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (date_one <= '2019-01-08 03:07:06-05'::timestamp with time zone)) OR ((date_two >= '2012-01-07 04:05:06-05'::timestamp with time zone) AND (date_two <= '2019-01-08 03:05:06-05'::timestamp with time zone)))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 18"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=12198 read=270298"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=24997.52..24997.52 rows=778752 width=8) (actual time=820.550..820.550 rows=377405 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14743kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=323 read=16887"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on fs_invoice_quote invoicequo0_  (cost=0.00..24997.52 rows=778752 width=8) (actual time=0.007..471.024 rows=777884 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=323 read=16887"
"Total runtime: 19412.432 ms"
```

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Have you tried applying indexes to the date columns, and rewriting this as a `UNION` query?

Comment: Is `date_two` in table A or B?

Comment: Hi @Randolph, could you please provide more details re. UNION approach and how that could be helpful to tackle order by issue?

Comment: the date_two is in table A (updated the question)

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables? Is there a foreign key from `A (b_id) REFERENCES B (b_id)` ?

Comment: Also, which version of Postgres (11, 10, 9.6, etc)?

Comment: Please share the present index structure on columns A.a_id or A.date_one or A.date_two if any. If they are not present already query need them created for better performance.

Comment: I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.13.

Comment: also I've noticed that it's sooner hash_join and seq_scan issue according to actual time

Comment: Just as a side note: 9.3.13 is out of support since November.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)